# How do I prevent trouble arising from std::string being constructed from `0`?

Tags: c++, string, g++, null-pointer

```
void foo (const std::string &s) {}

int main() {
  foo(0);   //compiles, but invariably causes runtime error
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler (g++ 4.4) apparently interprets `0` as `char* NULL`, and constructs `s` by calling `string::string(const char*, const Allocator &a = Allocator())`. Which is of course useless, because the `NULL` pointer is not a valid pointer to a c-string. This misinterpretation does not arise when I try to call `foo(1)`, this helpfully produces a compile-time error.

Is there any possibility to get such an error or warning at compile-time when I accidentally call a function like

```
void bar(const std::string &s, int i=1);
```

with `bar(0)`, forgetting about the `string`, and actually meaning to have `i=0`?

Comment: Not really without some help from the compiler. Some implementations have added a private `basic_string(int)` to catch this case. If not, I guess you are out of luck.

Comment: I'm surprised that this pass gcc, it's known for its ugly errors/warnings, but I would have expected something here. Did you crank up the warning level ?

Comment: @Matthieu I could not find any options that give me a warning, but I'm not really into gcc warning options. `-W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual` does not do the trick, at any rate.

Comment: I tested with clang (using gcc headers), and it didn't trigger any warning either :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is kind of ugly, but you could create a template that will produce an error when instantiated:

```
template <typename T>
void bar(T const&)
{
    T::youHaveCalledBarWithSomethingThatIsntAStringYouIdiot();
}

void bar(std::string const& s, int i = 1)
{
    // Normal implementation
}

void bar(char const* s, int i = 1)
{
    bar(std::string(s), i);
}
```

Then using it:

```
bar(0); // produces compile time error
bar("Hello, world!"); // fine
```

Comment: +1 even though this approach fails if `T` actually has a public static method called `youHaveCalledBarWithSomethingThatIsntAStringYouIdiot` and takes no arguments ;)

Answer (score 1):

One somewhat clean workaround...

```
#include <cassert>

void foo (const std::string &s)
{
    // Your function
}

void foo(const char *s)
{
     assert(s != 0);
     foo(std::string(s));
}
```

Comment: Except this is run-time, not compile-time.

Comment: @robert I know, it's just one possible solution.

Answer (score -2):

Actually static asserts would work too.
consider this:

```
void foo (const std::string &s)
{
    // Your function
}

void foo(const char *s)
{
    #ifdef CPP_OH_X
    static_assert(s == 0, "Cannot pass 0 as an argument to foo!");
    #else
    typedef int[(s != 0) ? 1 : -1] check;
    #endif
    foo(std::string(s));
}
```

The idea here is to use static_assert which is a upcoming feature in C++ and is already implemented in various compilers; primarly the ones that support C++0x.  Now if you're not using C++0x you can use the alternitive method, which basicly typedefs an integer with a negitive value on failure.  Something which is not allowed and will produce an error at **compile time**

Comment: This certainly looks cleaner than the template hack, but it does not seem to work: `implctstringparam.cpp: In function ‘void foo(const char*)’:
implctstringparam.cpp:9: error: ‘s’ cannot appear in a constant-expression`

Comment: The const std::string& s would most likely need to be static inorder for static assertion to work.

Comment: The value of `s` is only known at runtime, when the function is called:  you cannot use it in a `static_assert`, which is evaluated at compile-time.  A `static_assert` can only evaluate constant expressions.